# Subset of dictionary with aliases

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am looking for a good concise way to find the subset of a dictionary `o` whose keys contained in the set `option_set`, or an alias of their key is in the option set.

```
o = Dict{Symbol,Any}(:a=>2,:b=>1.0,:c=>1//2,:d=>1,:e=>3.0)
options_set = Set([:a :d :f])
aliases = Dict{Symbol,Symbol}(:c=>:d,:b=>:f)
# I want the dictionary of the intersection, including the aliased names
# i.e. Dict(:a=>2,:d=>1,:f=>1.0) or Dict(:a=>2,:d=>1//2,:f=>1.0) (which one is easier?)

#Starting idea
Dict([Pair(k,o[k]) for k in (keys(o) ∩ options_set)]) # Dict(:a=>2)
Dict([Pair(k,o[k]) for k in ((keys(o) ∪ values(aliases)) ∩ options_set)]) # Dict(:a=>2,:d=>1)
```

Is there a good way to handle using the aliased key to get the right value in the resulting dictionary?

---

Edit: I realized that it's much easier to just have the aliases in the other direction, i.e.

```
aliases2 = Dict{Symbol,Symbol}(:d=>:c,:f=>:b)
dict1 = Dict([Pair(k,o[k]) for k in (keys(o) ∩ options_set)])
dict2 = Dict([Pair(k,o[aliases2[k]]) for k in (keys(aliases2) ∩ options_set)])
merge(dict1,dict2)
```

Still wondering if there's a way of accomplishing the task from the original dictionary which is more direct than inverting it first.

Comment: Your question confuses me. What do you mean by 'aliases' in this context? If it means what I think it means, shouldn't `:c` and `:d` not refer to different things in `o` ?

Comment: It means the standard definition of alias. Yes, in a real case you wouldn't want `:c` and `:d` to be different values. I put it like this in the example since this is a problem that can occur, and I noted in the example that because this part is undefined, I'd take either value.

Comment: but, then, your problem is ill-posed. There is no "right value" if you have a contradiction in your set.

Comment: unless of course, you define a custom rule that "resolves" the contradiction. But that would be an arbitrary rule and completely up to you to define.

Comment: It's well-posed if I say I say I don't care. A solution can take the always give `:c`, can always give `:d`, or be random between them. I don't care about which rule.

Comment: Well, there you go, that's your resolution rule then. Have one list comprehension explicitly applying the rule to resolve contradictions first, and then another one like you have done to obtain the values.

Comment: That's what the first example I put up when asking so the question so obviously it doesn't answer it... the problem is that it still leaves off `:f`. Can `:f` be gotten (generally) without "flipping" the values of the dictionary?

Comment: having aliases in the other direction is important since it allows multiple aliases for a single key (and the original direction allows one alias to reference different options which is not useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be more performant to invert the dictionary, but you could always just write out the loop.

```
julia> result = Dict{Symbol, Any}()
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 0 entries

julia> for (k, v) in o
           if k in options_set
               push!(result, k => v)
           elseif haskey(aliases, k)
               push!(result, aliases[k] => v)
           end
       end
Dict{Symbol,Any} with 3 entries:
  :a => 2
  :d => 1
  :f => 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I haven't found answer on 'stackoverflow', so I share the code working in Julia 1.7.2.

"way to find the subset of a dictionary o whose keys contained in the set option_set"

```
o_result = filter( p -> p[1] in options_set , o)
```

"or an alias of their key is in the option set."

```
alias_result = filter( p -> p[2] in options_set, aliases)
```